# RelativeLayout inside ScrollView doesn't scroll. What i'm doing wrong?

Tags: android, android-layout, scrollview, android-relativelayout

I'm trying to make scrollable a landscape layout. I put my `RelativeLayout` inside a `ScrollView`, but nothing happens. Here's the code:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:fillViewport="true"
android:gravity="center_horizontal">

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/green_light"
    tools:context="app.example.ui.SplashActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/parent_center"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:src="@drawable/logo" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/parent_center"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll_gateway_discovery"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/parent_center"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/registration"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_large"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/who_are_you"
            android:textColor="@color/grey_dark"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_normal"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/et_username"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:minWidth="240dp"
            android:hint="@string/prompt_email"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_normal" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/et_password"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:minWidth="240dp"
            android:imeActionId="@+id/login"
            android:imeActionLabel="@string/action_sign_in_short"
            android:imeOptions="actionUnspecified"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="pippo"
            android:hint="@string/password"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_normal" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/btn_login"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_submit" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

What I'm doing wrong? It is driving me insane :)

Answer (score 1):

Use Linearlayout instead of relativeLayout

Answer (score 0):

use `HorizontalScrollView` instead of `ScrollView` as normal ScrollView is vertical scroll only

and with scrollView child to be wrapContent in width/height .. for horizontalScrollView width

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are using match_parent instead of wrap_content as layout_width and layout_height for the RelativeLayout. For example if you want to scroll vertically you have to use this:

```
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

With this the RelativeLayout will have the same width as the ScrollView but the height will be as big as the views inside it.

Resulting xml:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/green_light"
        tools:context="app.example.ui.SplashActivity" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/parent_center"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:src="@drawable/logo" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/parent_center"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll_gateway_discovery"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/parent_center"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/registration"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_large"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/who_are_you"
                android:textColor="@color/grey_dark"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_normal"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/et_username"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="8dp"
                android:hint="@string/prompt_email"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:minWidth="240dp"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_normal" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/et_password"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="8dp"
                android:hint="@string/password"
                android:imeActionId="@+id/login"
                android:imeActionLabel="@string/action_sign_in_short"
                android:imeOptions="actionUnspecified"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:minWidth="240dp"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="pippo"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_normal" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/btn_login"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:background="@drawable/btn_submit" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: nothing to do. it doesn't work. inside the RelativeLayout there a LinearLayout

Comment: Well explain, how does it not work exactly? I edited my answer to give more detail. In which direction do you want to scroll? And are you sure the views inside the RelativeLayout extend beyond the size of the ScrollView?

Comment: i want to scroll a landscape layout vertically

Comment: what do you mean nothing to do? I can only guess If you don't give me more information. For starters, post your complete layout xml, there must be something else wrong with it.

Comment: i've post the entire layout

Comment: I already edited my answer. There were problems with namespace declarations, they belong in the root node, and there were some problems with match_parent/wrap_content. With the layout I posted it's working.

Comment: Well it works for me so the layout cannot be the problem. Please explain a little more what exactly is not working. It just doesn't scroll, but the views inside do strech beyond the ScrollView?

Comment: But the views do extends beyond the ScrollView? Could you post a screenshot?